# How to find mean time of list of 24hr format time?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a list of time in 24hr format like:

```
times <- c(23.9, 0.5, 22.7, 0.1, 23.3, 1.2, 23.6)
```

I'm trying to find the mean of times... I can't seem to find a way and the `mean()` function is giving wrong answer.

This is what I tried:

```
mean(times)
```

How can I get the correct mean of times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clock has a circular scale, which ends where it begins, so you need to use circular statistics

```
install.packages("psych")
library(psych)
circadian.mean(bed.times) # This will give the correct mean
```